# Join JSON objects on common property

Tags: javascript, json, geospatial, join

is there an easier/more efficient way to join two JSON objects on a common property than this? It's a [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) file (basically an array of objects), and I want to pull in a property from another JSON file (array of objects) based on a common property, similar to a SQL `SELECT a.*, b.* FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id`

```
$.when(
    $.getJSON('https://data.phila.gov/resource/bbgf-pidf.geojson'),
    $.getJSON('https://data.phila.gov/resource/r24g-zx3n.json?%24select=count(*)%20as%20value%2C%20%3A%40computed_region_bbgf_pidf%20as%20label&%24group=%3A%40computed_region_bbgf_pidf&%24order=value%20desc')
).done(function(responseGeojson, responseData) {
    var data = responseData[0]
    var geojson = responseGeojson[0]

    // Create hash table for easy reference
    var dataHash = {}
    data.forEach(function(item) {
        if(item.label) dataHash[item.label] = item.value
    })

    // Add value from hash table to geojson properties
    geojson.features.forEach(function(item) {
        item.properties.incidents = +dataHash[item.properties._feature_id] || null 
    })

    console.log(geojson)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice a query on one of your urls. I suggest you use jQuery's [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) to construct the query cleanly.

For your first loop, you could use `reduce` instead of `forEach` to generate your hash. Additionally, you might want kill `NaN` early. You don't want to be carrying `NaN` in any data structure, otherwise you'll get some unexpected `NaN` in your code.

```
var dataHash = data.reduce(function(hash, item) {
  var value = +item.value
  hash[item.label] = isNaN(value) ? null : value;
  return hash;
}, {});

geojson.features.forEach(function(item) {
  item.properties.incidents = dataHash[item.properties._feature_id];
});
```

As for efficiency, I guess that's about it. You don't want to be nesting a lookup inside the other loop. Two separate loops is better then one nested inside another.

Comment: Thanks Joseph! Didn't realize `reduce` could be used that way

Answer (score 1):

Just want to follow up with something I learnt today: The creation of a hash map can be accomplished more easily using lodash or underscore's [indexOf](http://devdocs.io/lodash/index#indexBy) function.

```
$.when(
    $.getJSON('https://data.phila.gov/resource/bbgf-pidf.geojson'),
    $.getJSON('https://data.phila.gov/resource/r24g-zx3n.json?%24select=count(*)%20as%20value%2C%20%3A%40computed_region_bbgf_pidf%20as%20label&%24group=%3A%40computed_region_bbgf_pidf&%24order=value%20desc')
).done(function(responseGeojson, responseData) {
    var data = responseData[0]
    var geojson = responseGeojson[0]

    // Create hash table for easy reference
    var dataHash = _.indexBy(data, 'label')

    // Add value from hash table to geojson properties
    geojson.features.forEach(function(item) {
        item.properties.incidents = +dataHash[item.properties._feature_id].value || null 
    })

    console.log(geojson)
})
```